# Vincular informações do modelo em uma ListView de forma correta

Tags: java, android

Para recuperar um objeto do meu domínio a partir do evento `AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener` vinculado a minha ListView adicionei ao ViewHolder do adapter utilizado por esta uma referência ao meu objeto de domínio.

```
public static class ViewHolder {
    private TextView descricao;
    private TextView outraInformacao;
    private MeuObjeto meuObjeto;

    public MeuObjeto getMeuObjeto() {
        return meuObjeto;
    }
}
```

E procedi da seguinte forma para recuperar esta referência:

```
private AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener itemLongClickListener = new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

        MeuAdapter.ViewHolder viewHolder = (MeuAdapter.ViewHolder) view.getTag();

        Toast.makeText(context, viewHolder.getMeuObjeto().getId(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        return false;
    }
};
```

Para implementar o Adapter utilizei o ArrayAdapter:

```
public MeuAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<MeuObjeto> {
    ...
}
```

Minha classe de domínio contém atributos simples: String e Long. Os atributos do tipo String são utilizados para renderizar alguma informação e os do tipo Long guardam chaves primárias que podem ser utilizadas para recuperar informações. Para ser mais exato esta classe contém dez atributos, dois do tipo Long e outros oito do tipo String.

**É considerada uma má prática incluir em um ViewHolder informações que não sejam da view? Existe alguma implicação negativa, seja por questões de desempenho, ou quaisquer outras que pesem contra essa abordagem?**

Comment: Que informações tem esse objecto? De que tipo é o seu adapter? É um cursor adapter?

Comment: @ramaral, inclui na pergunta informações sobre o modelo e sobre o adapter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se o que você pretende é obter o objecto `MeuObjeto` que está associado ao item clicado da *ListView*, o *ArrayAdapter* disponibiliza o método [getItem(position)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html#getItem%28int%29) para isso.

Ele pode ser usado no `OnItemLongClickListener()`(ou `OnItemClickListener()`) desta forma:

```
private AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener itemLongClickListener = new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

        MeuObjeto meuObjeto = (MeuObjeto)parent.getAdapter().getItem(position);

        Toast.makeText(context, meuObjeto.getId(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        return false;
    }
};
```

Comment: Não consegui utilizar o método `getIem()`. Ele não está visível para mim, contudo o método `getItemAtPosition()` funciona perfeitamente.

Comment: Tem razão, não é visível porque faltou fazer a chamada a `getAdapter()`. Resposta editada.