# Menu de contexto flutuante não funciona em ListFragment

Tags: android, context-menu

Estou desenvolvendo um App que utiliza um DrawerLayout para apresentar um menu lateral. Um dos itens apresentados por este menu é uma ListFragment. Na minha ListView quero exibir um [menu de contexto flutuante](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html#FloatingContextMenu).

No `onCreateView()` da minha ListFragment fiz o binding de minha lista e executei o método `registerForContextMenu()`:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_list, container, false);

    ListView listView = (ListView)rootView.findViewById(android.R.id.list);

    registerForContextMenu(listView);

    return rootView;
}
```

Para apresentar o menu executei o método `onCreateContextMenu()`:

```
@Override
public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v, ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
    MenuInflater  inflater = getActivity().getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.contextmenu, menu);
}
```

**Código do menu**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:id="@+id/item1"
        android:title="Item 1" />

    <item android:id="@+id/item2"
        android:title="Item 2" />

</menu>
```

**Layout utilizado na ListFragment**

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ListView
        android:id="@android:id/list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@android:id/empty"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal">

        <ProgressBar
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleLarge"
            android:id="@+id/progressBar"/>

    </LinearLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```

Apesar de aparentemente estar tudo normal o menu não aparece ao segurar o item da ListView. Ao debugar o código percebi que em nenhuma das outras fragments o método onCreateContextMenu() é executado, somente na Activity responsável por trocar os fragments. Como resolver este problema?

Comment: Você tem algum `OnItemLongClickListener()` atribuido a essa *ListView*?

Comment: Tenho sim, @ramaral. Ele, inclusive é detalhado na pergunta sobre ViewHolder [http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/87609/vincular-informa%C3%A7%C3%B5es-do-modelo-em-uma-listview-de-forma-correta].

Comment: Já vi e vejo que está a retornar `false`, se retornasse `true` poderia estar aí o problema. Neste momento não sei mais o que poderá ser.

Comment: Alterando o valor de retorno de OnItemLongClickListener()  para `true` o onCreateContextMenu() de minha MainActivity não é mais chamado, contudo o método específico do fragment também não. Mantendo o retorno de OnItemLongClickListener() em `false` onCreateContextMenu() de MainActivity é chamado.

Answer (score 0):

Bom, trapalhadas acontecem às tantas por aí e eu tenho que fazer parte desse rol de trapalhões. Brincadeiras à parte, vou relatar aqui a raiz do problema para que sirva como um aviso do tipo "Não faça isso".

O código usado na pergunta **funciona perfeitamente**. E não precisa de **nenhuma** mudança para realizar o que deveria, que é exibir o menu de contexto.

A única observação que deixo é quanto ao retorno do evento `setOnItemLongClickListener` que deverá ser associado à ListView caso se queira captura o objeto da lista. Conforme explicado por **@ramaral**, para que o menu de contexto seja apresentado é necessário que o retorno de `OnItemLongClickListener` seja `false`.

**Vamos à trapalhada**

No meu projeto trabalho com objetos que contém as regras referentes a manipulação dos eventos da tela e requisições realizadas por AsyncTask. Este objeto de negócio mantém um atributo que contém uma referênia a Activity, chamado `context` e, neste caso específico uma referência a uma ListFragment, chamado `listFragment`. O problema de o menu de contexto não estar sendo apresentado é que em vez de eu chamar `listFragment.registerForContextMenu()` estava chamando `context.registerForContextMenu()`. O que por si só já era um grande erro visto que faço esse vínculo no `ListFragment.onCreateView`.